# Replacement for Using Except in nested query with IN in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am tring to use exception in my query but mysql does not support except. Is there any way to rewrite this query. The requirement is to use nest query IN Statement. So I cannot use exist.

```
select distinct course_id
From course As C 
Where C.course_id IN ((Select S.course_id
                      From Section As S
                      Where S.year='2019' AND S.semester='Fall')
                      EXCEPT (Select S.course_id
                      From Section As S
                      Where S.year='2018' AND S.semester='Spring'));
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want the query to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT IN insetead of EXCEPT:

```
select distinct course_id
From course As C 
Where C.course_id IN ((Select S.course_id
                      From Section As S
                      Where S.year='2019' AND S.semester='Fall')
                      and S.course_id NOT IN (Select S.course_id
                      From Section As S
                      Where S.year='2018' AND S.semester='Spring'));
```

Answer (score 0):

In MYSql ss replacement of except you can use `NOT EXISTS`. It's the pretty standard way to replace except.

```
select distinct course_id
From course As C 
Where C.course_id IN ((Select S.course_id
                      From Section As S
                      Where S.year='2019' AND S.semester='Fall'
                      not exists (Select S.course_id
                      From Section As Sec
                      Where Sec.year='2018' AND Sec.semester='Spring' and Sec.course_id=S.course_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (without subquery):

```
SELECT c.course_id
FROM course AS c
INNER JOIN Section AS s ON s.course_id = c.course_id
GROUP BY c.course_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(CAST(s.year AS CHAR(4)), s.semester)) LIKE '%2019Fall%' 
    AND GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(CAST(s.year AS CHAR(4)), s.semester)) NOT LIKE '%2018Spring%'
ORDER BY c.course_id;
```

If you only need the course_id field, so you do not need to join with the table course because the field course_id is in the table section too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Section.course_id` is defined as a foreign key of `course.course_id`, then you don't need the table `course` in your query.
Just `GROUP BY course_id` in the table `Section` and set the conditions in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT course_id
FROM Section
GROUP BY course_id
HAVING SUM(year='2019' AND semester='Fall') > 0
   AND SUM(year='2018' AND semester='Spring') = 0
```